Read transaction history
I have a full node installed and i have ogmios installed also, but i can't find a way to read full transaction history for any address. Is this even possible with cli or ogmios? Closest i found was this method in ogmios: "queryLedgerState/utxo" but that returns just some basic data, and not even close to any full transaction history.
Do I have to dig further into cardano-wallet API or even Cardano-graphql?
Any other ways i do not know?
I'm looking for native ways only, I want to learn everything myself, so I'm not interested in any third-paty APIs.

No, you cannot read the full transaction history for an address just from the node (with or without Ogmios). You need an indexing service like Kupo (or cardano-db-sync, but it's much heavier) for that.

Ogmios only interfaces with the ledger state which only tracks the current state of the chain. You need a full chain indexer like db-sync or a chain indexing wallet like cardano-wallet.

If you have Daedalus running you can use this:
https://forum.cardano.org/t/dump-wallet-transactions-with-cardano-cli/40651/6?u=erikd
